# How to get passed or failed test case name in the puppeteer

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, puppeteer

I need to integrate the puppeteer-jest test framework with TestRail using TestRail API. But for that, I need to know what tests are failed and what of the tests are passed

I Search some information in the official GitHub Repository and in the Jest site. But nothing about it.

Test:

```
describe('Single company page Tests:', () => {
    let homePage;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        homePage = await addTokenToBrowser(browser);
    }, LOGIN_FLOW_MAX_TIME);

    it('Open the company page from the list', async done => {
        await goto(homePage, LIST_PAGE_RELATIVE_PATH);
        await listPage.clickSearchByCompanyName(homePage);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.isPopupDisplayed(homePage);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.fillCompanyName(homePage, companies.century.link);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.clickNext(homePage);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.fillListName(homePage, listNames[0]);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.clickSave(homePage);
        await addCompanyNamePopup.clickViewList(homePage);
        const nextPage = await clickCompanyName(homePage, browser, companies.century.name);
        await companyPage.isOverviewTabPresent(nextPage);
        await companyPage.isPeopleTabPresent(nextPage);
        await companyPage.isSocialTabPresent(nextPage);
        await companyPage.isFinanceTabPresent(nextPage);
        await companyPage.isLeaseTabPresent(nextPage);
        await homePage.close();
        done();
    });
}
```

I expected to get all passed and failed test cases name and write it to JSON with the name of test cases and the result of them.
Actually, I have nothing of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use true/false assertion approach I like I do in my github *[project](https://github.com/storenth/web-developer-toolkit)*.
for example, try anchor case to some final selector with simple `assert`:

```
    describe('E2E testing', () => {
        it('[Random Color Picker] color button clickable', async () => {
            // Setup
            let expected = true;
            let expectedCssLocator = '#color-button';
            let actual;
            // Execute
            let actualPromise = await page.waitForSelector(expectedCssLocator);
            if (actualPromise != null) {
                await page.click(expectedCssLocator);
                actual = true;
            }
            else
                actual = false;
            // Verify
            assert.equal(actual, expected);
        });
```